# Connect Lumia 532 to PC with Bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth

Can I connect Lumia 532 to PC (Win7HP) by Bluetooth so I can explore what files are inside?

I can do it with a USB cable, that is not a problem, but I didn't find anywhere how to do it via Bluetooth. Only managed to connect it by Easy Transfer, but there I can see only Photo, Music and Video files. I want to manage the same connection by Bluetooth as by USB cable.

Answer (score 3):

Bluetooth does not allow you to see all the files that are on another device. You can however send files from your phone to your pc and vice versa.

If you want to see all files USB is currently the only way to go.